# How to monitor Cpu usage for my commands?

Tags: python, linux, debian, cpu-usage

I want to monitor my project in different parts to find out which part is consuming more CPU usage. I think it's possible in two ways:
1- before each command get CPU usage, of course it can't be efficient because maybe the command last long and I cant check CPU usage during the execution of command.
2- Create a monitoring daemon which monitors that specific process's CPU usage in milliseconds and log them some where and simultaneously log the time in my project and compare together.

1- Please let me know if there is any other way to do this?
2- Please tell me how to get specific process CPU usage?
I'm using python 2.6 on Linux Debian

Answer (score 3):

Gathering data on what parts of program use most resources is called profiling. Python has tools for this task in standard library, see:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

If this is not enough, you can google for 'python profiler' to find other tools, that better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice if you can log the information after some interval about your process from the

> /proc/PID/

directory. Linux based system maintains the information about the running process into its virtual "proc" directory. Now it maintains the enormous information about process resources utilization.The complete information about this can be found from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).You may want to explore this and find where kernel stores the useful information which suits your requirement.  Sometime back I had written some shell script fetch this information about the process(input is PID) of your program. You can get the information from my blog

http://mantoshopensource.blogspot.in/2011/02/proc-direcory-information.html

Now if you can log these information and put some logging in your program then you can verify that which part of your program is taking more CPU memory usage. Once you have broadly identify the module in your program which is causing the problem, then you can go for some dynamic tool or do static code analysis.

Hope you would find it of some use.